# rigify - add a Finger during animation

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups, rigify

I am using blender 2.77 and working with the riggify add-on. I have made some walk and run animations with my alien, so far so good. While I was playing around with the alien's hands to grab around a weapon I recognized I am missing phalanx on each finger. So my alien won't be able to hold the weapon (at least it looks really poor)

Is there any way to save my work I've done the last 2 days, such as the walking and running animations, and edit my rig - lets say like adding the missing phalanxes and regenerate the vertex groups via the generate button? To rework just the hand animations in my walk/running animations - I would love to do just that

So is there any correct way to edit a generated rig after animations? Or do i have to reanimate everything?

If you guys want I can send you the blender file

Comment: * maybe it is interesting to know:
This is my first time using rigify. In the beginning i deleted all four palm bones,because i just didnt know where to place them. As well as the pinky, because my alien just has 3 fingers.

Comment: IIRC you should be able to add a new bone in edit mode without any impact on animations as they all save their changes as differences from the bind pose.

Answer (score 1):

Once a rigify rig is created, it can be treated the same way as every other rig.

The armature modifier creates a relationship between a bone from the rig and a vertex group of the mesh with EXACTLY THE SAME NAME of the bone.

So: select your rig, go to edit mode, extrude <kbd>E</kbd> or divide <kbd>W</kbd> your finger bones until you're happy with the result, give to all modified bones a proper name, select the character, in the properties window - vertex tab - create new vertex groups with the same name of the new or modified bones, weight them manually using the "assign" button under the vertex group tab, and his relative value slider.
Assign "1.0" value of every vertex of the finger near to a bone, except near the junction: in those cases assign "0.5" value to both bones of the junction.

As tkausl said in the comments, you'll not loose any part of the already done animation, as soon as you do not modify the bones involved in your animation.

Also deleting unecessary bones from a rig is OK.

Comment: The automatic generated vertexgroups, bones (fk/ik), shapes and stuff is really complex and confusing for a beginner like me. Thank you for explaining. I redid everything now, because i got better understanding of the ik/fk slider and settings now and i can work much faster. 
I regenerated my rig from scratch, where i just deleted the pinky on each hand and keep every other bone. Everything is fine now except the palm shades on each hand acting weird on scaling. But i think i should be able to ignore or fix it via weight paint.